# GdipSaveImageToFile(), pointer to a Structure/Class in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winapi, gdi+, dllimport

I am using `GdipSaveImageToFile()` from GDI+ dll. It works all right if I send a null pointer in the last parameter (EncoderParameters)

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)>
Friend Shared Function GdipSaveImageToFile(image As IntPtr, filename As String, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.[In]> ByRef clsid As Guid, encparams As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Sub test(hbmp as IntPtr, filename as String, clsid as Guid)
    Dim status as Integer = GdipSaveImageToFile(hbmp, filename, clsid, IntPtr.Zero)
    If status <> 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error status = " & status)
    End If
End Sub
```

The code saves the image to a file using the standard settings.

Now, I have been strugling sending a real pointer in the last parameter (EncoderParameters) in vb.net.

Here is my attempt:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)>
Friend Shared Function GdipSaveImageToFile(image As IntPtr, filename As String, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.[In]> ByRef clsid As Guid, ByRef encparams As cEncoderParameters) As Integer
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=2, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Friend Structure cEncoderParameter
    Public GUID As Guid
    Public NumberOfValues As UInt32
    Public type As UInt32
    Public Value As IntPtr
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=2)>
Friend Class cEncoderParameters
    Public Count As UInt32
    Public Parameter As cEncoderParameter
End Class
Friend Enum cEncoderParameterType As UInt32
    EncoderParameterValueTypeByte = 1      ' 8-bit unsigned int
    EncoderParameterValueTypeASCII = 2     ' 8-bit byte containing one 7-bit ASCII code. NULL terminated.
    EncoderParameterValueTypeShort = 3     ' 16-bit unsigned int
    EncoderParameterValueTypeLong = 4      ' 32-bit unsigned int
    EncoderParameterValueTypeRational = 5  ' Two Longs. The first Long Is the numerator, the second Long expresses the denomintor.
    EncoderParameterValueTypeLongRange = 6     ' Two longs which specify a range of integer values. The first Long specifies the
    '                                            lower end And the second one  specifies the higher end. All values are inclusive at both ends
    EncoderParameterValueTypeUndefined = 7     ' 8-bit byte that can take any value depending on field definition
    EncoderParameterValueTypeRationalRange = 8 ' Two Rationals. The first Rational specifies the lower end And the second specifies
    '                                            the higher end. All values are inclusive at both ends
    EncoderParameterValueTypePointer = 9       ' A pointer to a parameter defined data.
End Enum

Sub b(hbmp As IntPtr, filename As String, clsid As Guid)
    Dim eps As New cEncoderParameters
    eps.Count = 1
    eps.Parameter.GUID = Encoder.Quality.Guid
    eps.Parameter.NumberOfValues = 1
    eps.Parameter.type = cEncoderParameterType.EncoderParameterValueTypeLong
    eps.Parameter.Value = New IntPtr(10)

    If GdipSaveImageToFile(hbmp, filename, clsid, eps) <> 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End If
End Sub
```

But the code breaks at the `GdipSaveImageToFile()`, with the following message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in TWAIN.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I also tried to change EncoderParameter definition from Class to Structure, and the following code

```
Dim pEnc As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(eps))
Marshal.StructureToPtr(eps, pEnc, False)

status = GdipSaveImageToFile(hbmp, filename, clsid, pEnc)

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pEnc)
```

But I get a similar error message

Any ideas? I am burn out :)

---

**Additional information**: Definitions from gdiplusimaging.h, gdiplusflat.h

```
class EncoderParameter
{
public:
    GUID    Guid;               // GUID of the parameter
    ULONG   NumberOfValues;     // Number of the parameter values
    ULONG   Type;               // Value type, like ValueTypeLONG  etc.
    VOID*   Value;              // A pointer to the parameter values
};

class EncoderParameters
{
public:
    UINT Count;                      // Number of parameters in this structure
    EncoderParameter Parameter[1];   // Parameter values
};

GpStatus WINGDIPAPI
GdipSaveImageToFile(GpImage *image, GDIPCONST WCHAR* filename,
                GDIPCONST CLSID* clsidEncoder, 
                GDIPCONST EncoderParameters* encoderParams);
```

Comment: eps.Parameter.Value doesn't point at anything

Comment: You may refer to the line 'eps.Parameter.Value = New IntPtr(10)' . It is my understanding that  New IntPtr(10) creates a pointer to an integer value 10.

Comment: No. It creates a pointer whose address is 10. And that's an invalid address. You need to create an integer, pin it,  and get the address of the pinned object. Or allocate unmanaged memory and write the value in to that memory.

Comment: Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)
    Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, 10)
    eps.Parameter.Value = ptr 
    status = GdipSaveImageToFile(hbmp, filename, clsid, eps)                  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Remember to destroy the memory when done with it.

Comment: I am still getting the same error with that code (sorry I cant get it formatted the right way in this comments)

Comment: What about the definition     <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)>
    Friend Shared Function GdipSaveImageToFile(image As IntPtr, filename As String, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.[In]> ByRef clsid As Guid, ByRef encparams As cEncoderParameters) As Integer
    End Function

Comment: Thank you David Heffernan! The 4th parameter needs to be a pointer. So I used Marshal.StructureToPtr to convert my cEncoderParameters to a Ptr and the function works! thanks a lot

Comment: I think UnmanagedType.LPStruct could be used to avoid that complexity.

Comment: It makes very little sense to P/Invoke GDI+ functions in VB.NET. The Graphics library in the BCL already wraps almost everything from GDI+. It certainly wraps the ability to save an image to a file!

Comment: @Cody Gray, I agree with you. However I am getting an image using TWAIN_32.dll, DSixfer(), it gives you a handle to a Bitmap/DIB that somehow it is not compatible with Dim img As Image = Image.FromHbitmap(hDIB). The error: Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.